# Angular 6+ How to use inner functions with class variables?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to use array.filter(my_func()) when processing 5 different arrays of user inputs to elegantly return the array without the element the user just deleted, with a private filterInput class variable. However, my_func() when used as an inner call doesn't have "this" context.

Is there a better way to do this? Would rather not write the same filter function in 5 different callers just to keep scope.

```
MyClass
    private inputArray1: string[];
...
    private filterInput: string;
...
    private filterFunc(element, index, array) {
        return (element !== this.filterInput);
    }
...
    public caller1(input: string) {//this is called from the onclick() in the HTML
        this.filterInput = input;
        this.inputArray1 = this.inputArray1.filter(this.filterFunc());
    }
```

Anyone know how to accomplish this without scrapping the filter utility and just writing my own using search then return slice1 + slice2?

Comment: Look into lambdas ("arrow functions")

Comment: Do you really need to store the `.filterInput` on your instance at all?

Comment: @Bergi, not necessarily if there's a better way to do it (which the parameterised double return solution below looks to be). It's just the first thing that came to mind. I am an Angular novice on a big project with a tight timeline just doing what feels natural in other languages I've used. Primary backgrounds are Java and C++. I'm always open to learning though.

Comment: @patrickjp93 Thanks, I adjusted my answer below. The fourth snippet in malbarmawi's answer (if that's what you mean by "double return") is close, but you wouldn't even make a separate method to create the closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functions bind method to fix `this` reference

```
public caller1(input: string) {
  this.filterInput = input;
  this.inputArray1 = this.inputArray1.filter(this.filterFunc.bind(this));
}
```

or you can use javascript arrow function

```
public caller1(input: string) {
  this.filterInput = input;
  this.inputArray1 = this.inputArray1.filter((elm,idx,arr) => this.filterFunc(elm,idx,arr));
}
```

another way be javascript functions closure ‍♂️

```
private filterFunc() {
    const filterInput = this.filterInput;
    return function (element, index, array) {
         return (element !== filterInput);
}

public caller1(input: string) {
    this.inputArray1 = this.inputArray1.filter(this.filterFunc());
}
```

but I do prefer to use parameter like this to set the filter value

```
private filterFunc(filterInput) {
    return function (element, index, array) {
         return (element !== filterInput);
}

public caller1(input: string) {
    this.inputArray1 = this.inputArray1.filter(this.filterFunc(this.filterInput));
}
```

[**Closures**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: Thanks for that last answer. I love recyclable code.

Answer (score 0):

For general solutions of how to solve this, see [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572), but for [the `filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) specifically just pass the context as the second argument:

```
this.inputArray1 = this.inputArray1.filter(this.filterFunc, this);
//                                                          ^^^^
```

This is relatively unidiomatic though. You wouldn't make the `filterFunc` an instance method at all, you'd just define a local function inside the `caller1` method and make it a [closure over the `input` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572):

```
public caller1(input: string) {
    function filterFunc(element, index, array) {
        return (element !== input);
//                          ^^^^^
    }
    this.inputArray1 = this.inputArray1.filter(filterFunc);
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

or doing the same, but more concisely by defining the function inline as an expression, using arrow syntax and omitting the unneeded parameters:

```
public caller1(input: string) {
    this.inputArray1 = this.inputArray1.filter(element => element !== input);
}
```

Comment: I'm going with the closure answer to return the result of an inner function since it's more reusability. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is to write your "filterFunc" like this (ts compiler will not put it on a prototype):

```
private filterFunc = (element, index, array) => {
    return (element !== this.filterInput);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
this.inputArray1 = this.inputArray1.filter(this.filterFunc);
```